# Figuring out if a number is a palindrome

Tags: haskell

I'm relatively new at Haskell and I have no idea why this won't compile. What I'm trying to do is create a function that checks if a number in string form is a palindrome by creating a helper function that does that. Thanks!

```
isPalindrome :: [Char] -> Bool
isPalindrome s = (helper . Char.digitToInt) s
    where helper [] = True
          helper [x] = True
          helper (x:xs) = x == (last xs) && (helper . init) xs
```

Errors:

```
euler.hs:29:28: error:
• Couldn't match type ‘Int’ with ‘[a0]’
  Expected type: Char -> [a0]
    Actual type: Char -> Int
• In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘Char.digitToInt’
  In the expression: helper . Char.digitToInt
  In the expression: (helper . Char.digitToInt) s
euler.hs:29:45: error:
• Couldn't match expected type ‘Char’ with actual type ‘[Char]’
• In the first argument of ‘helper . Char.digitToInt’, namely ‘s’
  In the expression: (helper . Char.digitToInt) s
  In an equation for ‘isPalindrome’:
      isPalindrome s
        = (helper . Char.digitToInt) s
        where
            helper [] = True
            helper [x] = True
            helper (x : xs) = x == (last xs) && (helper . init) xs
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't compile because `digitToInt` takes a `Char` and returns an `Int`.

You're giving it a list (`s :: [Char]`) and treating the result as another list (`helper` takes a list).

Comment: Ahh, I see now! Adding map seemed to fix the issue. Thanks for the quick response! :)

Comment: @Ben why are you converting characters to `Int`s when it's entirely acceptable to compare the characters in the first place?  In other words, if you already have a string representation of the number then it suffices to check if the string is a palindrome.

Comment: @Ben now that you see what's going on in this case, I would suggest reading the error message again carefully. I think you'll find it's pretty clear (if a little verbose), and it's the sort of error you're going to encounter again and again. Also be sure to mark this question as answered

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson I see what you mean. There's really no reason for me to convert the characters to Ints. I was just working out the Project Euler problems and one of the requirements for it was to check if a number was a palindrome. I guess I didn't realize that the conversion was unnecessary in this case. Thanks for pointing that out!